# Mathematica `fourier` get different result with python `np.fft`

Tags: list-manipulation, complex, fourier-analysis, python

In python,I run fft as below:

```
t = np.arange(10)
s = np.sin(0.15*2*np.pi*t)
S = np.fft.fft(s)
print(S)

[ 1.96261051+0.00000000e+00j  3.65687576-4.44089210e-16j
 -2.90211303+6.58456965e-16j -0.90211303+2.77704128e-16j
 -0.57919222+1.15109392e-16j -0.50952545-5.24550760e-18j
 -0.57919222-1.15109392e-16j -0.90211303-2.69216718e-16j
 -2.90211303-6.58456965e-16j  3.65687576+4.40847308e-16j]
```

For checking the result, I run the same fourier transform in Mathematica v13.0 linux as below:

```
t = Range[0, 9];
s = Sin[0.15*2*Pi*t];
Fourier[s]
{0.620632, 1.15641, -0.917729, -0.285273, -0.183157, -0.161126, \
-0.183157, -0.285273, -0.917729, 1.15641}
```

What make Mathematica give me float result of `Fourier`?

Comment: It all comes down to different definitions of [Fourier Transform](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier.html#DetailsAndOptions). Use ``Fourier[s, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]`` to get the same results as in python.

Comment: @Domen,why mathematica output float,not complex?

Comment: @kittygirl notice that the j part is so small, it may just some inaccuracy.

Comment: @AsukaMinato,I believe Mathematica  is more professional than python,but not?

Comment: OP, what is trying to be said is that the imaginary part made by numpy is not truly there. That is, it is effectively 0. It’s appearance is likely a result of numerical error.

Comment: @CATrevillian,fourier transform of real data should be complex data.

Comment: Hmm, I get the Python results from your Mathematica code (with `FourierParameters -> {1, -1}`) in V13.0 Mac M1 Max: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvdpS.png  (And your literal code gives me complex numbers, too.)

Comment: @MichaelE2,same version with linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
t = Range[0, 9]
s = Sin[0.15*2*Pi*t]
Fourier[s,FourierParameters-> {1,-1}]
```

Comment: There's no imaginary part.

Comment: In your python solution, look at the imaginary parts. They are something multiplied by 10 to the power of -16. This is effectively zero, and an artifact of numerical methods you are using in Python. These are not actual imaginary numbers if you perform exact operations.

Comment: @kittygirl out of topic: there are errors around the float, such as https://0.30000000000000004.com/, even 0.1+0.2!=0.3, so python gives 1e-16 is reasonable.

Answer (score 7):

If the FFT has any non-zero imaginary parts then you'll get a complex array as you expect:

```
Fourier[{0, 1, 2, 3}]
(* {3. + 0. I, -1. - 1. I, -1. + 0. I, -1. + 1. I} *)

Head /@ %
(* {Complex, Complex, Complex, Complex} *)
```

However if the imaginary parts are all zero then *Mathematica* returns a real array:

```
Fourier[{0, 1, 2, 1}]
(* {2., -1., 0., -1.} *)

Head /@ %
(* {Real, Real, Real, Real} *)
```

There's nothing wrong with this, you just need to be aware that the *type* of the output from `Fourier` depends on the *value* of the input, unlike most other FFT implementations which always return complex types.

Comment: Michael E2's comment tell me the same result in Mac version.